# where to ask discussion related questions especially for web business?

Tags: discussion, search

where to ask discussion related questions-especially for web business?

If not from stackexchange site. direct me to any other popular site.

There are many question closed because many users dont know where to ask discussable questions.

Comment: Nick, an example would be : finding web based business module?

Comment: Is the _chat_ section for discussion?

Comment: Good question, +1

Comment: @w3d: I personally find SE's chat to be of little value, and I've never seen SE's chat logs in any Google search results.

Comment: Sangee, in thinking about it, guessing you're unlikely to get a good answer either because no one here goes to sites like that, or they're so hard core about SE that they'd never suggest another site for fear you'd never return to SE

Answer (score 3):

Every stackexchange site starts off with a similar FAQ which discourages open ended discussion. Some may allow limited discussion on certain topics, such as the literature site which allows book recommendations.

There is http://answers.onstartups.com/ for starting up businesses but their [faq](http://answers.onstartups.com/faq) says.

> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and
>   push other questions off the front page.

You probably need to look somewhere else than stackexchange if you want discussion.

Comment: +1 A search for "web business forums" or "internet startup forums" should yield many places to chat about business ideas and issues.

Comment: -1 Your answer simple restates what is already know by the person asking the question, and does not address the question, that being: For web forum discussion of web business, what websites would be the best options?

Answer (score 1):

I agree, SE should allow a mirror link or an additional sign in requirement, where people might discuss in depth.

I think SE guys don't want to hamper there ratings and standards in terms of google.

They must be really user oriented.

Comment: My guess is that they know the quality of content would go to hell, and it quick order the SE would die, which is why the don't have a section that allows open ended, subjective, etc. questions; because people would get sucked in and never spend time on the real q&a sites.